# AX 2009: Report Range on enums parsing enum value commas?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I think I may have found an interesting bug with AX 2009, and I'm unsure of how I can proceed.

I am attempting to write a new report, and one of the conditions of this report is to be filtered based on the Posting field of the LedgerTrans table. However, it seems that when the report goes to execute, the label of the enum `Purchase, receipt` is parsed without regard to the quotes. This normally wouldn't be a problem, but the enum label in this case contains a comma. The result is that when run the query dialog box reads: `Purchase, consumption, __ILLEGAL_VALUE__.` I get this result even if I use the enum value or name. The report must be left interactive, but this field must be locked, so we cannot get the users to adjust the query at run time.

At this point I don't want to change the label itself, but if it is the only way to solve this I will. Has anyone else run into this, or know how we could overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before.  Sometimes an acceptable option is hard-coding the conditional values as an OR statement, rather than the comma separated list:

```
((LedgerTrans.Posting == LedgerPostingType::PurchReceipt) || (LedgerTrans.Posting == LedgerPostingType::PurchConsump))
```

That can be typed into a range filter box, or can be set as the value of a range via x++ code:

```
ledgerPostingRange.value("((LedgerTrans.Posting == LedgerPostingType::PurchReceipt) ||
                           (LedgerTrans.Posting == LedgerPostingType::PurchConsump))");
```

AX doesn't try to convert these to the labels, so they stay as distinct values, instead of being rendered as labels.  Note that parentheses are required for it to be parsed properly.

Since the **ILLEGAL_VALUE** can appear even when attempting to use a single value that contains a comma in its label, the same can be done for a single :

```
ledgerPostingRange.value("(LedgerTrans.Posting == LedgerPostingType::PurchReceipt)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change the label! But as a workaround you could use the enum value's number instead.

If the field is often queried, you could put the field in a dialog then change the query:

```
 ledgerPostingRange.value(ledgerPostingType ? int2str(ledgerPostingType) : '');
```

Comment: I have attempted to use the numeric value of the enum, but it still pulls the same result. I will change the label in the meantime, but this obviously isn't a desired result, especially since this is a system enum. 
Interestingly enough, this DOES work properly if you enter it on the user side, just not if you pre-define it on a report (and possibly other) query.